# Is there any way to put a directory name instead of a single file name as a key in AWS Lambda test event?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have been working on fetching the s3 (.csv) data through the lambda function and putting it into the dynamodb. I have enabled a trigger on S3 bucket so when any file is uploaded to the bucket it automatically the content of the file to the Dynamodb table through the lambda function.

Lambda Function

```
import json 
import boto3 

s3_client = boto3.client("s3") 
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
student_table = dynamodb.Table('AgentMetrics')
 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_bucket_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    file_name = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    
    file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name,Key=file_name)
    print("file_object :",file_object)
    
    file_content = file_object['Body'].read().decode("utf-8")
    print("file_content :",file_content)
    
    students = file_content.split("\n")
    print("students :",students)
    
    for student in students:
        data = student.split(",")
        try:
            student_table.put_item(
            Item = {
                "Agent" : data[0],
                "StartInterval" : data[1],
                "EndInterval" : data[2],
                "Agent idle time" : data[3],
                "Agent on contact time" : data[4],
                "Nonproductive time" : data[5],
                "Online time" : data[6],
                "Lunch Break time" : data[7],
                "Service level 120 seconds" : data[8],
                "After contact work time" : data[9],
                "Contacts handled" : data[10],
                "Contacts queued" : data[11]
           } )
        except Exception as e:
            print("File Completed")
```

I am using s3 put event in lambda function and putting my bucket name on the required places. You can see the test event following:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "new-bucket-for-metrics",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::new-bucket-for-metrics"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "AgentMetrics-2022-02-23T14:30:00Z.csv",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Everything is working fine when I put "key": "AgentMetrics-2022-02-23T14:30:00Z.csv", It means it is only picking a single file from the s3 bucket. **But I want to pick a whole subdirectory like this**:  "**key": "AgentMetrics/**"  or "key": "**connect/oblab2/Metrics/AgentMetrics/**",

So whenever a file is uploaded to this directory it will automatically trigger the lambda function and we don't have to put the name of the file every time manually.
I have tried but this doesn't work, maybe not doing it properly. When I try to do this Lambda function throws an error that you can see the following:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.",
  "errorType": "NoSuchKey",
  "requestId": "e306187e-8713-42d6-8366-065b9f875947",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 15, in lambda_handler\n    file_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=source_bucket_name,Key=file_name)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 386, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 705, in _make_api_call\n    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)\n"
  ]
}
```

I have spent last week creating Lambda script, now there is only one task is remaining. I don't have any idea how to achieve this, kindly share your valuable thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

The S3 test event will always include the full key (directory name + file name) of the single file that triggered the event. There will never be just a directory name in the event passed into Lambda.

However, the event passed to Lambda is not the same as the S3 Trigger settings, and you seem to be confusing those two things. You can absolutely [setup a trigger for a prefix](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-s3-adds-prefix-and-suffix-filters-for-lambda-function-triggering/).

Also note that directories don't actually exist in S3, they are just part of the object keys, and are referred to as object key prefixes.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. So, it means what I am trying to achieve isn't possible here. Can you please elaborate on how I can achieve this?

Comment: What do you think isn't possible exactly? You want S3 to notify Lambda of any new files that show up in a folder/directory/prefix, and Lambda will be triggered on each file and perform the appropriate inserts of that file into DynamoDB.

Comment: Yes, I exactly want that that you just said. My main intention is to automate the whole thing so, I don't have to put file name every time.

Comment: Then do exactly what I described in my answer.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you. Can you please describe the exact guidance in steps?  What to change in my scenario?

Comment: The only thing you need to change is the S3 trigger configuration. I gave you a link that walks you through that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242385/discussion-between-rehan-ch-and-mark-b).